# int pointer being realloc'd was not allocated C

Tags: c, pointers, int, malloc, realloc

I've seen other people ask this but don't seem to see an answer, or the issue was with chars or some other problem. I really can't figure out why this error is coming up because I AM allocating. My original code is much longer but I simplified to what was getting the error and the exact same error is coming up, so this is where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addInteger(int **iArr, int *newI, int * count);
int main(){
    int* iArr = malloc(0);
    int iCount = 0;
    int newInt = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d",&newInt);
        iCount++;
        iArr = realloc(iArr, sizeof(int*) * iCount);
        addInteger(&iArr, &newInt, &iCount);
    }
    free(iArr);
    return 0;
}
void addInteger(int **iArr, int *newI, int * count){

    iArr[*count-1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    iArr[*count-1] = newI;
}
```

Running it with my inputs gives an error on the second number:

Enter number: 1

Enter number: 3

a.out(1291,0x7fffb62df380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeed674b78: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Abort trap: 6

Comment: `sizeof(int*)` is not proper for `iArr`..it needs to be size of `int`..

Comment: `iArr[*count-1]` is incorrect, `iArr` points to a single pointer and you malloc'd memory in the function is overritten in the line after it. What are you trying to do? An array of pointers to int or an array of ints?

Comment: I was trying to do an array of pointers to ints. I see I wasn't declaring correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors with your dereferencing:

The variable `iArr` is a pointer to array of type `int`.

But you are passing its address to `addInteger` and then replacing this address with a random input value.

Then, this random input value gets passed to `realloc` instead of the pointer you allocated, which is now gone.

And so you get the error.

Lets fix you code to avoid this:

```
//NOTE: there is no need to pass newI and count as pointers, because the function does not change them!
void addInteger(int **iArr, int newI, int count);
int main(){
    //1. If you want iArr to be array of pointers, you need to start with ** pointer to pointer
    //2. Just initialize with NULL, when realloc gets NULL it works just like malloc
    int** iArr = NULL;
    int iCount = 0;
    int newInt = 0;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d",&newInt);
        iCount++;
        iArr = realloc(iArr, sizeof(int*) * iCount);
        //You do not need to pass addresses here because your function does not change its parameters
        addInteger(iArr, newInt, iCount);
    }

    free(iArr); //this will cause a memory leak!
    //you need to loop over the array and free each integer first.

    return 0;
}

void addInteger(int **iArr, int newI, int count){
    iArr[count - 1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *iArr[count - 1] = newI;
    /* Note the * here - it is important!
       Without it, you would overwrite the pointer you just allocated in the prevoius line
       But the * tells the compiler "put the int value at the address specified by the array
    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried a couple different versions, most of the code was in the function, which is why I was passing by reference, but I was trying to pinpoint what part of the function was causing the error so stuff got moved around. I was trying to do array of pointers, I see I did it wrong. thank you. Thanks for the point about free().

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through the program one statement at a time.

```
int* iArr = malloc(0);
```

`iArr` is either `NULL` or points to an object of size 0.

```
int iCount = 0;
int newInt = 0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
```

In the first iteration, we have `i = 0`.

```
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&newInt);
```

Let's say the user entered `42` here, so `newInt = 42`.

```
    iCount++;
```

Now `iCount = 1`.

```
    iArr = realloc(iArr, sizeof(int*) * iCount);
```

This is suspicious: `iArr` is declared as a pointer to int (which can be used to point into an array of integers), but you're not allocating space for `iCount` integers, you're allocating space for `iCount` pointers to int.

If `iArr` is meant to be a dynamic array of pointer to int, it should've been declared as
    int **iArr;

If `iArr` is meant to be a dynamic array of int, this call should be changed to

```
iArr = realloc(iArr, sizeof (int) * iCount);
```

or (preferably):

```
iArr = realloc(iArr, sizeof *iArr * iCount);
```

This latter form is always correct<sup>1</sup>, no matter how `iArr` is declared.

(Passing `NULL` as the first argument to `realloc` is fine, so it doesn't matter what exactly `malloc(0)` returned initially.)

```
    addInteger(&iArr, &newInt, &iCount);
```

Let's inline this function here (I've changed the parameter names to make it more obvious what's going on):

```
    int **addInteger_iArr = &iArr;
    int *addInteger_newI = &newInt;
    int *addInteger_count = &iCount;
```

We initialize the function parameters.

```
    addInteger_iArr[*addInteger_count-1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

OK, so what does this line actually do? We know the value of `addInteger_count`; it's `&iCount`, so let's just plug that in:

```
    addInteger_iArr[*(&iCount)-1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`*` and `&` cancel each other out, giving:

```
    addInteger_iArr[iCount-1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`iCount` is `1` and `1-1` is `0`, so this becomes:

```
    addInteger_iArr[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Similarly, let's plug in the value of `addInteger_iArr`, which is `&iArr`:

```
    (&iArr)[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`a[b]` is defined as `*(a + b)` by C, so this line means:

```
    *(&iArr + 0) = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Adding `0` does nothing, and `*` and `&` cancel each other out, so we get:

```
    iArr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Hey! We've just lost the old value of `iArr` (the pointer returned by `realloc`). This is a memory leak.

```
    addInteger_iArr[*addInteger_count-1] = addInteger_newI;
```

The left-hand side of the assignment is the same as in the previous statement; `addInteger_newI` is the same as `&newInt`:

```
    iArr = &newInt;
```

Hey! We've just lost the old value of `iArr` (the pointer returned by `malloc` in the previous statement). This is another memory leak.

Furthermore, `iArr` no longer points to dynamically allocated memory; it points to `newInt`, which is just a local variable.

```
}
```

Now we start the second iteration of the loop. This crashes in `realloc(iArr, ...)` because at that point `iArr` is set to `&newInt`.

---

There are several possible ways to fix this code.

If you just want a simple dynamic array of integers, you should change your loop to:

```
    iCount++;
    iArr = realloc(iArr, iCount * sizeof *iArr);
    iArr[iCount-1] = newInt;
```

And if you want to move that last statement into a function:

```
    addInteger(iArr, iCount, newInt);
```

with

```
void addInteger(int *iArr, int iCount, int newInt) {
    iArr[iCount-1] = newInt;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, the size calculation is correct. You still need to check whether `realloc` failed, in which case it returns `NULL` and you need to `free` your pointer manually, and in general you should check for integer overflow in the `size * items` calculation.